# jQuery does not select elements (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using Insert Headers and Footers plugin for Wordpress and I am trying to embedd some javascript code will react to the user's actions.

So this is the simple code that I have tried:

```
$("a#newsLetter").click(function() { 
    alert("element was clicked");  
});
```

I also tried:

```
$( "#newsLetter" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert("element was clicked");
});
```

Both did not work, even though I know that jQuery is loaded and included ( I performed a simple test and of alerting some message on page load)

This is the tag shown in the inspector:

```
<a href="#" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-xl" role="button" id="newsLetter">
```

Thanks.

EDIT:
[image: This] This is how I included jQuery

Comment: What was your simple test? Are you sure that only one `#newsLetter` element exists in the DOM? Have you put your jQuery code inside a document.ready handler?

Comment: Does your jquery working properly??

Comment: Checked your console? Any errors? Jquery Included?

Comment: The test was as I mentioned, instead of selecting an element ($'#newsLetter')..... I simply wrote alert("jQuery is loaded"); and it did show

Comment: alert("jQuery is loaded");  will work as an alert - even if jQuery is not loaded - you need to test it with a jquery selector or method

Comment: it could be due the to the href being "#" -   try removing that and see if the click handle works.

Comment: @gavgrif True, I have edited the post and added an image showing how I added jQuery

Comment: What do you see in the page when you do `console.log(jQuery)` and `console.log($)`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I do not see anything...

Comment: Sorry, I meant check the console. You should either see a jQuery object or `undefined` in either case

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ReferenceError: $ is not defined , ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: There we go. Your reference to the jQuery library isn't working. That's the problem.

Comment: Doesnt work on header as well, most searches on google of how to add jQuery result in the code that I have added in the edit above.

Comment: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" ....here is your problem your reference is not working.

Comment: Ok the problem was the "true" field that I marked while adding jQuery. Changed it to false so it would not be in the footer, now I have jQuery. On clicking now says too much recursion, but that is a different problem. Thanks alot to all !

Comment: Glad you got it working.. almost :) Just FYI, that error normally means you've created an infinite loop somewhere. Normally from nested event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

Use the three parameter form, it applies to elements added after the click handler has been added:

```
$( document.body ).on( "click", "#newsLetter", function() {
  alert("element was clicked");
});
```

Comment: @RanAB Not sure if WP defines `body`, i think the console should log that body is not defined. Try replacing `body` with `document` (only for testing, for live you want to use the closest static parent instead)

Comment: $( document ).on( "click", "#newsLetter", function() {
  alert("element was clicked");
}); may be you should try this

Comment: Check the comments under the question. The error is `ReferenceError: $ is not defined , ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

If jquery not working then try this

```js
document.getElementById("newsLetter").onclick =function(){
  alert('clecked');
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-xl" role="button" id="newsLetter">Link</a>
```

Comment: Not working for some reason, no error is outputed to the console

Comment: Check the comments under the question. The error is `ReferenceError: $ is not defined , ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that's why I have suggested that

Comment: Removing jQuery to solve this is like killing the patient to cure the disease.

Comment: nicely said but eventually, it's going to find the disease. It could be something like 
 that JavaScript himself not working

Comment: I detailed the issue under @RoryMcCrossan response on the top. Thanks to all

Comment: great to hear that

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `$` with `jQuery`

```
jQuery("a#newsLetter").click(function() { 
    alert("element was clicked");  
});
```